# Javascript Destroydrop tree - loading dynamic ajax data

Tags: javascript, ajax, tree

Using JS Destroydrop tree - http://destroydrop.com/javascripts/tree/ .CSS & .JS

It is simple to have rendered tree when the data for the tree is hardcoded in the html file.
data example:

```
<div class="dtree">

<p><a href="javascript: d.openAll();">open all</a> | <a href="javascript: d.closeAll();">close all</a></p>

<script type="text/javascript">
    <!--

    d = new dTree('d');

    d.add(0,-1,'My example tree');
    d.add(1,0,'Node 1','example01.html');
    d.add(2,0,'Node 2','example01.html');
    d.add(3,1,'Node 1.1','example01.html');
    d.add(4,0,'Node 3','example01.html');
    d.add(5,3,'Node 1.1.1','example01.html');
    d.add(6,5,'Node 1.1.1.1','example01.html');
    d.add(7,0,'Node 4','example01.html');
    d.add(8,1,'Node 1.2','example01.html');
    d.add(9,0,'My Pictures','example01.html','Pictures I\'ve taken over the years','','','img/imgfolder.gif');
    d.add(10,9,'The trip to Iceland','example01.html','Pictures of Gullfoss and Geysir');
    d.add(11,9,'Mom\'s birthday','example01.html');
    d.add(12,0,'Recycle Bin','example01.html','','','img/trash.gif');

    document.write(d);

    //-->
</script>
```

The tree has to be re-rendered with dynamic ajax data.
Fetching the data dynamically means the single line is fetched from api, this is already done:

```
    d = new dTree('d');
    d.add(0,-1,'My example tree');
    d.add(1,0,'Node 1','example01.html');
    d.add(2,0,'Node 2','example01.html');
    document.write(d); <---- the is feteched from the API, if written in console then the entire page goes blank, and then the tree is displayed on the blank page.
    .....
```

How can this data be added dynamically?

I have tried:

- giving and id to the script tag, and using the js
  getElementByID.innerHTML();
- same as above with the required comment tags
- using the eval() function

c. the required comment tags inside the script make this a bigger challenge:

Comment: You can write a tree of data structures and loop through layer by layer

Comment: After I fetche the code from API, how do I execute it? If I type it in console or using eval() then the etire page goes blank and only the tree is shown.

Comment: ajax Or array??

Comment: No arrays anywhere.

Comment: I want to insert:

Comment: I want to insert "d=new dTree('d')......." Dynamically , as you can see in the code above it is wrapped by comment block inside the script tag.

Comment: my idea is ` d.add(0,-1,'My example tree');
    d.add(1,0,'Node 1','example01.html');
    d.add(2,0,'Node 2','example01.html');
    d.add(3,1,'Node 1.1','example01.html');
    d.add(4,0,'Node 3','example01.html');
    d.add(5,3,'Node 1.1.1','example01.html');
    d.add(6,5,'Node 1.1.1.1','example01.html'); `

Comment: I'm going to loop through an array

Comment: is your idea using backticks? 
the thing is if I receive that string from the API, as a String how do I execute it?
eval() is not working because the whole page goes blank....

.innerHTML() , well is not html

plus I need to execute it inside the comment block, kind of weird but 100% possible, I had it a year ago... and it was a one or two three line solution

Comment: You write each layer of data into an array to form a tree structure. You have too much code